# How do I limit access to a REST API to only match a user's id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Given a REST API with an endpoint like this (defined using OpenApi):

```
/user/{id}:
  get:
    summary: Get info of specified user, perhaps showing account details.
```

Where `{id}` is a path parameter specifying the id of a user.

If the API is being called from a web browser, and a user has an id of `123`, how is it best to limit the user to only being able to call `/user/123` and not any other `id`, e.g. `/user/456`?  Do I need to design the API so that is has an endpoint for the current user only, e.g. `/user`?

Assume that the user must log in to access the API.  Better still if you can describe how best to do this with AWS ApiGateway and Amazon Cognito user pools.

Answer (score 2):

I think your options are

1. Use cognito user pools with API Gateway integration and write additional backend code for the user/ID method to check access (seems sloppy, I don't recommend doing this)
2. Use an API Gateway custom authorized (without cognito) which would allow you to check whatever you want before accepting/denying access
3. Use cognito user pools with API Gateway integration and, as you say, "design the API so that is has an endpoint for the current user only, e.g. /user". I think this is by far the cleanest method of the three

Note that I've only researched, and haven't personally done tons of Cognito work.

Comment: The 3rd option is byfar the best way to implement it.